# I built the BPNN model with keras in python, and the final score of both the training set and the test set was 0.8

Tags: python

I built the BPNN model with keras in python, and the final score of both the training set and the test set was 0.8. Then I used this model to predict new data. In the first prediction, I did not normalize the data, and the results of prediction processing were all the same, so I normalized the data and then made prediction. After the prediction was completed, I made anti-normalization, but the predicted result was very different from the actual result. I've been trying to figure it out for a long time.

- I tried a lot of things, and it could be a problem with my data
- dataset = pd.read_csv(r'F:\shuju\1.csv')

  from sklearn import preprocessing

  sc_X=preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

  sc_Y=preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

  x=dataset.iloc[:, 0:8].values

  y = dataset.iloc[:, 8].values

  y = np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))

  x=sc_X.fit_transform(x)

  y=sc_Y.fit_transform(y)

  # min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

  # dataset=min_max_scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

  # df0=min_max_scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

  # dataset = pd.DataFrame(df0)

  # x=dataset.iloc[:, 0:8].values

  # y = dataset.iloc[:, 8].values

  print(x)

  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25,random_state=123)

  print('train and shape', X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
- from keras.models import Sequential

  from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation

  from keras.optimizers import Adam

  model_3 = Sequential()

  model_3.add(Dense(64, input_dim = 8, activation = 'relu'))

  model_3.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))

  model_3.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))

  model_3.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))

  model_3.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))

  model_3.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))

  model_3.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_absolute_error', metrics = ['mean_absolute_error'])

  model_3.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_test, y_test), epochs = 300, batch_size = 16)

  #

  plt.plot(model_3.history.history['loss'])

  plt.plot(model_3.history.history['val_loss'])

  plt.title('Model training and validation loss curves')

  plt.ylabel('Loss')

  plt.xlabel('Epochs')

  plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation'], loc = 'upper right')
- y_train_predict=model_3.predict(X_train)

  y_test_predict=model_3.predict(X_test)

  ```
  print('train MAE/MSE/MAPE')
  print(mean_absolute_error(y_train_predict, y_train))
  print(mean_squared_error(y_train_predict, y_train) )
  # print(mape(y_train_predict, y_train) )
  print('R2：{}'.format(round(metrics.r2_score(y_train, y_train_predict), 4)))
  print('test MAE/MSE/MAPE')
  print(mean_absolute_error(y_test_predict, y_test))
  print(mean_squared_error(y_test_predict, y_test) )
  print(mape(y_test_predict, y_test) )
  print('R2：{}'.format(round(metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_test_predict), 4)))
  ```
- ```
  #train MAE/MSE/MAPE
  #0.05352500831318932
  #0.00861800592343811
  #R2：0.8133
  #test MAE/MSE/MAPE
  #0.05597242918793313
  #0.009151299969903695
  #28.01357173666271
  #R2：0.8035
  ```
- #prediction

  data = pd.read_csv(r'F:\shuju\2.csv')

  sc_X=preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

  x=data.iloc[:, 0:8].values

  x=pd.DataFrame(sc_X.fit_transform(x))

  apply=x.iloc[:, 0:8].values

  predict=model_3.predict(apply)

  pre=sc_Y.inverse_transform(predict)

  print(predict.shape)

  print(pre.shape)

  print(format(predict))

  submission=pd.DataFrame(pre)

  print(submission.shape)

  print(submission)

  submission.to_csv(r'F:\shuju\prediction.csv',index=False)